# Is there support in Cordova to WKWebView?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, wkwebview

I would like to know if is possible use WKWebView with cordova. And if this is possible, how I can use.

I read that cordova 4.0 maybe will use WKWebView, but I can't find if this is in production.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a plugin for `WKWebView`
https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView

cordova 4 will bring `WKWebVIew` support, but it won't be the default webview (iOS 7 doesn't support `WKWebView`, so they can't just replace it without removing iOS 7 support)

You can read a blog post with more information about cordova 4 and the `WKWebView` support by the cordova iOS developer
https://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2015/03/03/wkwebview-and-apache-cordova/

Edited to add this:
Crosswalk project (cordova like project, compatible with cordova, but using a chromium based webview on android) has launched an iOS crosswalkview, that is based on WKWebView too 
https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/ios.html